# Is it possible for two areas to share the same route and still both be reachable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two areas that register routes as shown below:

"Website" area:

```c#
context.MapRoute(
    "Landing Controllers",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

"Mobile" area:

```c#
context.MapRoute(
    "Mobile Defaults",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "MobileHome", action = "Index" },
    new { controller = "MobileHome", action = "Index" }
);
```

By default, one or the other of these routes would be consistently taken when trying to go to the root URL `/`. But suppose we decorated our controller actions with a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`, where the `OnAuthorization` method is overridden to redirect the user to the correct controller when appropriate, as below. (Idea taken from a great [blog post](http://www.chrispoulter.com/blog/post/redirecting-to-a-mobile-area-in-asp-net-mvc).)

```c#
public class MobileRedirectAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = // Logic to generate the ActionResult that conditionally
                     // takes us to the other route goes here.

        filterContext.Result = result;
    }
}
```

I've tried using a new `RedirectResult` and `RedirectToRouteResult`, neither of which work as I'd like because of the routing conflict. Is there a way to set `AuthorizationContext.Result` to a value that would take us to the action that we're not currently executing? (As a last resort, I can just prefix the mobile route with some sort of namespacing variable, but I'd like to avoid going down that road just yet.)

---

My question can probably also be summarized by having a look at Wikipedia's desktop/mobile routing. Their two sites, http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page also share identical routes, but, depending on which mode you're in, return very different results.

Would it be possible to set up Wikipedia's routing in an MVC project where each environment (mobile/desktop) is registered in its own area?

Comment: do you really need different controllers for mobile and non-mobile? or just separate view is enough?

Comment: @EugeneBrianOng Yeah, there's enough of a difference between their functionality to warrant separate controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague led me to a promising solution using a custom `IRouteConstraint`.

```
public class HelloWorldConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route,
        string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        // Determine whether to accept the route for this request.
        var browser = BrowserDetector.Parse(httpContext.Request.UserAgent);
        if (browser == BrowserPlatform.Mobile)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And my route declaration now looks like the below, where the route constraint is attached to a route parameter chosen at random.

```
context.MapRouteLowercase(
    "Mobile Defaults",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "MobileHome", action = "Index" },
    // In this case, it's not so much necessary to attach the constraint to
    // a particular route parameter as it is important to be able to inspect
    // the HttpContextBase provided by the IRouteConstraint.
    new {
        controller = new HelloWorldConstraint()
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with standard MVC Routing. You can probably do with attribute routing, available in either MVC 5 or via the nuget package, AttributeRouting.

Comment: Thanks for the notice! I didn't know that Attribute Routing was available in MVC5, definitely something to check out.

Comment: It's based on the AttributeRouting nuget package, but it doesn't support all the features of that package. With MVC5, you basically just get `RoutePrefix` for specifying part of the route on the controller itself and `Route` to specify the route for each action. AttributeRouting has many other features, such as support for Areas, subdomains, etc. I haven't tried, myself, but you should still be able to install AttributeRouting (the nuget package) on top of MVC 5 if you need the extra features.